# How to use request in pythonanythere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I tried

```
   import requests 
   url='https://www.cnn.com/'
   r=requests.get(url)
```

Error:

```
ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host=... port=80): Max retries exceeded with...
```

The following

```
print requests.utils.get_environ_proxies('http://www.google.com')
```

output:
http://proxy.server:3128

What can I do?

Thanks.

Jerry

Comment: You did not setup your proxy properly.

Answer (score 0):

www.cnn.com is not on the whitelist of sites that free accounts can access. To be included in that whitelist, a site needs to have a publicly documented API.